# Google Chrome - FATAL:NSS_util.cc(632) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: google-chrome, google

When I try to open Google Chrome, I get this:

```
[2922:2958:0913/051621.681319:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] 
NSS_versionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required.
Please upgrade to the latest NSS
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What should I do?

Comment: I had the same issue when im running google-chrome from terminal, 

I found that it needed a new version of NSS: Chrome 62 need NSS>=3.26. So I installed libnss3.

    $google-chrome

    [6999:7036:1113/200616.549496:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
    Aborted (core dumped)

 #sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3

and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to the top of your /etc/ld.so.conf:
(using e.g. nano)

```
/lib

/usr/lib
```

then

run ldconfig (or reboot) and try it again.

You should see /opt/google/chrome/chrome linked to the libraries in /usr/lib if you check it with ldd.

OR

1) build and install the mozilla-nss package. I used the one found in the Slackware 14.1 source, which is 3.15.2.

2) as above - add these lines to the top of /etc/ld.so.conf:
/lib
/usr/lib

3) Run ldconfig (or reboot)

source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/google-chrome-30-error-nss-4-13-5-upgrade-4175482053/

Comment: When I tried to run ldconfig, it said: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied

Comment: then simply reboot or try runing idconfig as root